# How to access JSON nested objects with ruby?

Tags: json, ruby

so I have a JSON file that is made of nested objects that follow the following pattern : `parent -> child -> grand_child` and looks like the following :

```
//seed.json
    {
      "parent_0":[
        {
          "child_10":[
            {
              "grand_child_A":[],
              "grand_child_B":[],
              "grand_child_C":[]
            }
          ],
          "child_20":[],
          "child_30":[],
          "child_40":[]
        }
      ],

      "parent_1":[
        {
          "child_11":[
            {
              "grand_child_D":[],
              "grand_child_E":[],
              "grand_child_F":[]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

What I am trying to do is to list all objects present in parents , child and grand_child with ruby.

I was able to pull that off with `parent` by doing the following :

```
# seed.json

json = File.read('seed.json')
content = JSON.parse(json).keys
```

which return the following :

```
$ ruby seed.rb
"parent_0"
"parent_1"
$
```

I'm stuck there ... I'd like to access `child_10` and list all its objects which are `grand_child_A`, `grand_child_B`, `grand_child_C`, the same way I did access and list `parent_0 and parent_1` but I have no idea how to proceed.

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific about what you mean by "access"? Do you want a list like `["grand_child_A", "grand_child_B", "grand_child_C", ""grand_child_D", "grand_child_E", "grand_child_F"]`? Or `["parent_0", "child_10", "grand_child_A", "grand_child_B"...]`? Or `[["parent_0", "child_10", "grand_child_A"], ["parent_0", "child_10", "grand_child_B"]...]`? Or an iterator that will provide those? Or do you not want a list, but something else? If possible, give an example of the output you want.

Comment: Okay, to make it simple, I'd like to list all objects below `child_10` which are all the grand_child.

Comment: `JSON.parse(json)["parent_0"][0]["child_10"].flat_map { |x| x.values }`, though I think I may be confusing you with this.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
require 'json'

json = File.read('seed.json')
content = JSON.parse(json)

parent = 'parent_0'
child = 'child_10'

content[parent].flat_map{ |e| e[child].flat_map { |ee| ee.keys} }

# => ["grand_child_A", "grand_child_B", "grand_child_C"]
```